# Missing hyperlink in The Overflow issue #2

Tags: bug, the-overflow

The Overflow is Stack Overflow's [new newsletter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams/). This post is feedback.

This morning's (Oct 17, 2019) distribution included an abstract and title regarding a news story about a blind man who sued Domino's Pizza, but no hyperlink. The link should point to https://www.cnbc.com/2019/10/07/dominos-supreme-court.html

> Supreme Court hands victory to blind man who sued Domino’s over site accessibility

Comment: What does this actually have to do with Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It has to do with the newsletter, The Overflow, which is nominally about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The newsletter contains a section called "Links from around the web". One of the "links" doesn't actually link to anything, it's just blue text.

Comment: It looks like this is only missing in the plain text version.  The html one has a working link.  Interestingly it's the only link in the html message that goes directly to the source instead of being wrapped by itr-links.stackoverflow.email which I assume is some sort of click counter service.