# Feedback/typo tag, as an addition to the possible categories?

Tags: feature-request

Presently, posts to meta require one of four tags in order for the post to succeed. Those are: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and [support](/questions/tagged/support). However, the [contact us page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) says

> To share product feedback on our products, please visit our community here

With the "visit our community here" portion being a hyperlink to meta.stackoverflow.com. This left me with a difficult decision on how my feedback should be categorized. If SO really wants feedback posted to meta, then it should be allowed, and I think it should be clearly labeled as such as well.

I propose adding a fifth option: `feedback` to the options for the required tag. If that is too much work, I suggest at least rewording the description/definition of one of the other tags (probably discussion) to clearly include feedback.

See the accepted answer here: [Where to send questions or concerns about the Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390518/where-to-send-questions-or-concerns-about-the-overflow)

And my later post, which apparently was a cause of confusion: [Missing hyperlink in The Overflow issue #2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390519/missing-hyperlink-in-the-overflow-issue-2)

**Edit:** After reading @CodyGray's answer, I agree that most "feedback" should probably be in the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. However, the need remains IMHO to separate non-conversational typo reports with actual software malfunctions. How about a "typo" tag, so that the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag can be reserved for malfunctions requiring developer attention, whereas "typo" would generally be something a moderator can fix (if there are any mods left at this rate), or (as in the case with the newsletter) cannot be fixed beyond the act of making available the correct content to those who go looking for it.

Related: [A better way to report broken links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312225/11529348)

Comment: It does not sound like meta is useful place for it currently (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388445/477420). If it is not twitter-able issue it may be easier to just ignore rather than spend your time researching/coming up with good new feedback... otherwise - twitter indeed :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see your point, but it doesn't make sense to me to tell users of one blog to go use another blog to deliver feedback about the former because the former can't be bothered to come up with an appropriate delivery method. If they do actually end up going that way, they should at least update the contact info page to point to their twitter/reddit/whatever.

Comment: "It does not sound like meta is useful place for it currently" and "it may be easier to just ignore" demonstrate the problem I seek to fix.

Comment: Moderators cannot, in general, fix any typos that regular users cannot fix. We can only edit posts on the Q&A site. We can’t edit the blog, and we can’t edit site UI elements. Those require an employee, so they need to be posted as bug reports. The [[meta-tag:bug]] tag does *not* imply a severity, so it is perfectly valid to tag typos or broken links as bugs. I don’t know why someone told you different. They were wrong. Note that getting downvotes on Meta doesn’t necessarily mean “you asked this in the wrong place” or that you mistagged. It may just mean people disagree it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

As you're using it, "feedback" is one of those words that sounds good, but doesn't have any actual meaning.

In certain technical fields, "feedback" has a very well-defined meaning: it refers to a situation where the outputs of a system are routed to its inputs, creating a circuit or loop.

In [management jargon](https://charlescrawford.biz/2008/10/11/art579/), "feedback" means something akin to "a user's thoughts." That meaning can be broken down into three distinct sub-divisions:

1. Bug reports ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug))—things that don't work at all or don't work as expected. For example, "This particular blog post has a broken link," or "[The overuse of emojis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386228/for-a-more-considered-use-of-emojis) in blog posts prevents me from reading them on my Commodore 64."
2. Feature requests ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request))—changes that you'd like to see made, either adding or taking away items. For example, "Allow opting out of the automatic email notifications," "Enable comments on the blog posts," or "Stop [displaying ads about Viagra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335577/yet-another-inappropriate-scammy-and-nsfw-ad)."
3. Everything else ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion))—the catch-all category for when you just have a thought, opinion, or feeling that you want to share, and/or when you aren't sure about your idea and want to get community input first. (A lot of "feedback" is naturally going to fall into this category.)

And then, of course, there is [support](/questions/tagged/support), which isn't really a sub-category of "feedback". It's for when you need assistance using one of the site's features and/or when you want someone with more privileges than you to do something that you cannot do yourself (like create a tag).

We already have all the category tags we need. A "feedback" tag wouldn't convey any additional information, and would only make it *more* difficult to categorize questions.

Comment: Bug: "This particular blog post has a broken link" That is exactly the scenario I ran into (on the newsletter), and made a post about it with the bug tag (linked in the question). Within an hour the post had a score of -6, with people saying the bug tag was inappropriate. I edited the question to point out that one of four tags is required, and bug seemed to be the best (as you apparently agree), and the score started going up. As it sits now, most of the bulk of that post is there to defend itself, that it is in the right place and has the right tag. This is why I made this suggestion.

Comment: Granted, I do agree that most usable feedback is probably more of a discussion, "I think this should be like this" and people weigh in. In the same way, I think most feature-requests could also fall into this category; I mean, how often does someone post an idea, and the devs/mods just do it without discussion? What I was trying to accomplish didn't really beg much conversation. Just "Hey, you guys messed up. In case anyone is looking for it, here's the link." Instead we ended up having a conversation - but about rather my choice of tag and forum were appropriate.

Comment: Bottom line: if "Bug" was the correct tag, the description should do a better job of reflecting that fact. Maybe then there would be less push back (downvoting) when the tag is used correctly.

Comment: As I said above, the bug tag is appropriate. You needn’t have justified your actions. Downvotes don’t imply “pushback”, as you’re interpreting it. They may just mean people don’t think your bug report is well presented, or they may disagree that the bug is worth fixing. I think the bug tag description is more than adequate. Regarding feature requests, think of it this way: [[meta-tag:feature-request]] is when you have a fully-formed feature request ready for review/comment; [[meta-tag:discussion]] is for when you have an idea but no concrete proposal on how to implement it. @mem